# How to run a ASM program in command prompt on Windows 10

Tags: assembly, command-prompt

I am new to assembly and was wondering if I am able to run an ASM program in my computer's command prompt. It so, how do I do it? If not, what application do I use to run it?

Comment: (1) Assembly your program to create an executable (EXE file), (2) open a command prompt window, (3) run the program ? Not sure I understand what the problem is.

Comment: You need a text editor to write the code, an [assembler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language#Assembler) to turn that code into binary object code, and a [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) to produce an executable. You can head over to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for what software is available to do this. But please do some legwork yourself first. You will need that most of all.

Comment: What command do I use to run it? I read online that I use the MASM command but when I try it, it says  that "MASM" is not an internal or external command.

Comment: You need to be familiar with basic concepts such as installing software and using search engines to find information before you should tackle programming at all, let alone assembly.

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/msdos.htm

Answer (score 2):

In the case of Windows, using Visual Studio express (it's free) or a similar tool set, you can create an assembly only project, build a .exe Windows console program, then run that program from a Windows console. I assume that something similar can be done with Linux or other Posix type systems. Visual Studio can create 32 bit or 64 bit programs.

If the goal is to create a 16 bit assembly program, you'll need a 16 bit tool set, such as Masm 6.11 or similar tool set (you might also want a 16 bit compiler like Visual C/C++ 1.52). If you're creating a small 16 bit .com program, you can use "debug" with a directed input file and directed output file as a crude assembler. 32 bit versions of Windows can run 16 bit MSDOS type programs, but on a 64 bit version of Windows, you'll need to use a virtual machine in either 16 bit mode (usually MSDOS) or 32 bit mode (usually some version of 32 bit Windows).